# bluetooth - btusb - How to replace module version with a newer one

Tags: linux, kernel-modules, bluetooth

I have pre-compiled kernel 3.16.7 which has btusb v0.6 module; The current btusb v0.6 I'd like to replace with btusb v0.7 which is located in kernel 4.0; So my question is how to :

- remove the current btusb 0.6 from kernel 3.16.7
- extract btusb 0.7 from kernel 4.0 (compile it)
- insert the compiled btusb 7.0 to kernel 3.16.7

**EDIT** :

lsusb outputs :

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04ca:2006 Lite-On Technology Corp.
```

the broadcom device 04ca is quite new so maybe that's the major problem;

*As I could get it, it needs btusb module version>=0.7; So I do need some kind of module replacement cause my current pre-compiled kernel has btusb 0.6; **I really want not to deal with the whole kernel sources compilation but to figure out btusb local integration into my already pre-compiled kernel v3.16.7***

**EDIT** :

I have $usb-devices output as :

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=02 Cnt=01 Dev#= 11 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=01 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=04ca ProdID=2006 Rev=01.12
S:  Manufacturer=Broadcom Corp
S:  Product=BCM43142A0
S:  SerialNumber=*******
C:  #Ifs= 4 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=(none)
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=(none)
I:  If#= 2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=(none)
I:  If#= 3 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=fe(app. ) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=(none)
```

after the input :

> sudo modprobe btusb

and...

> sudo echo "04ca 2006" | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/btusb/new_id

I can see btusb driver activated as $usb-devices:

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=02 Cnt=01 Dev#=  4 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=01 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=04ca ProdID=2006 Rev=01.12
S:  Manufacturer=Broadcom Corp
S:  Product=BCM43142A0
S:  SerialNumber=******
C:  #Ifs= 4 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
I:  If#= 2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=(none)
I:  If#= 3 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=fe(app. ) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=(none)
```

...

**EDIT**

I try to download an install linux-headers as :

```
sudo pacman -S linux-headers
[sudo] password for ...: 
:: There are 8 providers available for linux-headers:
:: Repository core
   1) linux310-headers  2) linux312-headers  3) linux313-headers
   4) linux314-headers  5) linux316-headers  6) linux318-headers
   7) linux319-headers  8) linux40-headers
```

*...but as I can get it the linux316-headers do install headers for 3.16.7.11-1-Arch; I can see it pretty clear cause after installation I have /lib/modules/3.16.7.11-1-Arch folder created :( Currently I have running kernel as 3.16.7.3-1 so the repo headers are not compatible or similar demanding me to upgrade; So is there a way to install headers which compatible with my kernel build version?*

p.s. I am quite new to linux so please link some related tutorials links and give detailed steps

Thanks

p.p.s.
OS : Linux Arch x64

Comment: What are you attempting to accomplish with this?  Do you have a device that is not working?

Comment: @Jeremy31 you are right; I have not working usb bluetooth which supposed to be supported by module version 0.7

Comment: Can you download the source code for the kernel?  Post results from `lsusb` as you can add your device to the current source and build the module

Comment: @Jeremy31 I cannot (don't know how) add my bluetooth device to the current btusb 0.6 module of pre-compiled kernel 3.16.7;  and if to mention kernel 3.16.x sources and how to integrate (replace) its modules manually please guide me :)

Comment: can you get linux-image with the same version as the headers you have?

Comment: @Jeremy31 yes, thanks for your comment;  just today I upgraded the whole system to synch linux and linux-headers versions (which I didn't want to trying to avoid upgrade cause sometimes it can crash the system :P ); So , yes, I have susceeded to install linux316-headers  3.16.7.11-1 package :)  But still it is a mistery for me is there a way to get the packages which are not related to update package the archived ones or similar which are related to the previous the non-upgraded-system? Cause, as I can see now, the repo-s allow to download the newest packages versions only :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to download the source code with

```
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.x/linux-3.16.7.tar.xz
```

Then you need to extract it

```
tar xpvf linux-3.16.7.tar.xz
```

Then cd into the correct directory

```
cd linux-3.16.7/drivers/bluetooth
```

When you post the result of `lsusb` I should be able to finish this answer

```
gedit btusb
```

Go to the end of line 116 which should be `{ USB_VENDOR_AND_INTERFACE_INFO(0x0489, 0xff, 0x01, 0x01) },`  Press Enter key twice, then Tab once and paste this in

```
/* Lite-On Technology - Broadcom based */
    { USB_VENDOR_AND_INTERFACE_INFO(0x04ca, 0xff, 0x01, 0x01),
      .driver_info = BTUSB_BCM_PATCHRAM },
```

Check the spacing and format to see if it matches the other entries, then save and exit gedit.

Then we can copy some configuration files into the directory

```
zcat /proc/config.gz > .config
```

Now we can build the bluetooth modules with

```
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$PWD modules
```

When they are compiled we can copy the btusb.ko to the kernel directory

```
sudo cp btusb.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/
cd /usr/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/
gzip btusb.ko
```

This bluetooth device needs firmware

```
cd ~
wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/xbmm9vfg2fby2zn/fw-04ca_2006.hcd
sudo cp fw-04ca_2006.hcd /lib/firmware/
```

Then we can unload btusb and load it so that the new version is loaded

```
sudo modprobe -r btusb
sudo modprobe btusb
```

Comment: The the current kernel I have (3.16.7) lsusb shows exactly unsupported bluetooth device see my question edit

Comment: This will just build the bluetooth modules for the kernel, not the entire kernel.  I updated the USB ID list 3 days ago for your device, so the desciption in lsusb should change after `sudo update-usbids`

Comment: Thanks but I have linux Arch OS running; So I am not sure concerning to apt-get and the linux-headers-generic; And please id all steps cause it's pretty hard to ask details :)

Comment: Skip the apt-get as it seems the equivalent of build-essential is usually installed and you likely installed kernel headers with the kernel image

Comment: But before integration of "bluetooth" kernel's folder and its btusb 0.7 into my pre-compiled kernel 3.16.7 I want to ask will the btusb 0.7 be compatible with kernel 3.16.7 cause, as I can see it, btusb version 0.7 only kernel 4.0 has? I couldn't find the info so please give me a tip

Comment: ...I just found I have "/lib/modules/3.16.7.3-1-Arch/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/" and all modules which stored there are archived as btusb.ko.gz (the current btusb 0.6); Does it mean I have to archive my manually compiled new module or its fine to have it not-archived?

Comment: quote : "EDIT; What happens if you trymodprobe btusb and then echo "04ca 2006" >> /sys/bus/usb/drivers/btusb/new_id" when I input the echo as: $sudo echo "04ca 2006" >> /sys/bus/usb/drivers/btusb/new_id ... I get error output as :  
bash: /sys/bus/usb/drivers/btusb/new_id: Permission denied

Comment: `echo "04ca 2006" | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/btusb/new_id`

Comment: the "sudo echo "04ca 2006" | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/btusb/new_id" outputs "04ca 2006" so now I can click "search device" but still it cannot find my mobile bluetooth; I am not sure concerning the echo cause should it be called every boot as a script for example?

Comment: I edited my question; Watch it please

Comment: what should I do next? Any ideas? Guide me please

Comment: I think you will have limited functionality of the bluetooth until the btusb can be modified for the patchram firmware loading.  Can you make the change to btusb.c and make the new module?  If you can make a new btusb.ko we can try to use insmod to see if it works before copying it to the kernel directory and changing it to btusb.ko.gz

Comment: I guess you are right; The current btusb 0.6 does not have info about device 04ca and there is no related firmware:( You mean decompile the currently installed btusb.c 0.6 modify its source code and write the re-compiled one over the old one? I am not sure concerning decompilation so please guide me how to do so?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to decompile a kernel module.  That is why my answer has instructions for downloading source code, changing the btusb.c file, and then compiling the new module

Comment: ok; so I should take btusb 0.6 from kernel 3.16.7 and modify it or take btusb from kernel 4.0 and just add firmware? or there is no way to integrate modules from one kernel to another? I am confused a bit

Comment: Take the btusb.c from 3.16.7 and modify it.  Trying btusb.c from 4.0 will likely result in errors because of changes and trying btusb.ko from 4.0 will definitely not work on 3.16.7 as modules are kernel specific.  If you want I can make the change to the btusb.c from the kernel source and upload the bluetooth folder to my dropbox account and then all you would have to do is copy your config files to the folder, compile, and install

Comment: Thanks; I'll try to compile and install according to your instructions by myself cause I have, as you mentioned, Arch OS x64; I am to try your answered steps and to report my results :) But still please identify the steps you propose to  lets say as A, B C, C1, D etc me to ref them if I want to find out more details or I face an issue in one of them

Comment: I did a big edit to the answer but I think the btusb.ko will have to be compressed to work correctly in Arch after a reboot

Comment: Yes, you are right; I just noticed the running btusb module looks like btusb.ko.gz in "...kernel/drivers/bluetooth/" ; And concerning the *.hcd file should it be placed to "/lib/firmware/" folder or "/lib/firmware/brcm"? I have noticed I have the "/lib/firmware/brcm" folder...

Comment: from what I saw in the kernel source, it needs to be in /lib/firmware/brcm/   If the new btusb works as expected we can `cd /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/` and then `sudo gzip btusb.ko`

Comment: You removed the USB_DEVICE(...) info so please add this tip of how to modify btusb; And concerning the USB_VENDOR_AND_INTERFACE_INFO or DRIVER_INFO what values they should have in my case?

Comment: I already added what you need to btusb.c in the wget command and changed the answer to get rid of unnecessary info

Comment: OK I got it; But I am not sure concerning the "cp /boot/config-$(uname -r) .config
cp /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/Module.symvers Module.symvers"? I have linux Arch OS so I don't have the mentioned files :P Give me a tip

Comment: You might be able to skip the command then

Comment: I just tried for kernel-3.16.7 bluetooth extracted folder input "make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$PWD modules" but I get the output as "make: *** No rule to make target 'modules'.  Stop." Does it mean I have to compile the bluetooth folder with the whole kernel folders set?

Comment: Try this and see if there are errors `wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/uoovkbe7chgh00p/btusb.ko` Then `sudo modprobe -r btusb` and `sudo modprobe -v ./btusb.ko`

Comment: I think I don't have proper linux-headers installed; I just checked the os repo contains too high linux-headers version which does not equal to my kernel version (I didn't update my os for too long cause I am not sure the newer kernel version will do work as stable as the current one); I want to ask is there a way somehow install linux316-headers 3.16.7.11-1 if I have kernel-3.16.7.3-1 currently running?

Comment: See if `locate Module.symvers` finds the file.  You should be able to `ls /usr/src/` to see what is there, that is where the header files are in Ubuntu and a search said Arch puts them there also

Comment: "locate Module.symvers" doesn't find kernel's file; The " ls /usr/src/" outputs linux-3.12.35-1-Arch/

Comment: An older post indicated that this command might work if you are in the bluetooth directory you downloaded from my dropbox link `make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=$PWD` annd see if btusb.ko is in the directory

Comment: I have output : "Entering directory '/usr/lib/modules/3.16.7.3-1-Arch/build'
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop." You mean I have to boot in linux-3.12.35-1 mode? I have a few kernels installed the 3.12 is the default one but it is quite unstable for my hardware so I run kernel-3.16.7 :'(

Comment: Try `make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$PWD modules`

Comment: I just tried but I get the output as "make: Entering directory '/usr/lib/modules/3.16.7.3-1-Arch/build'
make: *** No rule to make target 'modules'.  Stop." I am really confused  :"(

Comment: what does `pacman -Sy base-devel linux-headers-$(uname -r)` result in?  It may be easier to install the newer 4.0 kernel so the firmware can be loaded into the bluetooth device and then reboot(versus shutdown0 and use 3.16 as the firmware should only be lost during a shutdown

Comment: The kernel 4.0 contains btusb v0.7 which source still needs to be patched to support my bluetooth device; So If I install pre-compiled kernel-4.0 that won't help :P

Comment: After I removed /var/lib/pacman/db.lck the output is ":: Synchronizing package databases...
 core is up to date
 extra is up to date
 community is up to date
 multilib is up to date
 infinality-bundle is up to date
 infinality-bundle-multilib is up to date
...

Comment: ...continued...  infinality-bundle-fonts is up to date
:: There are 26 members in group base-devel:
:: Repository core
   1) autoconf  2) automake  3) binutils  4) bison  5) fakeroot  6) file
   7) findutils  8) flex  9) gawk  10) gcc  11) gettext  12) grep  13) groff
   14) gzip  15) libtool  16) m4  17) make  18) pacman  19) patch
   20) pkg-config  21) sed  22) sudo  23) texinfo  24) util-linux  25) which
:: Repository multilib
   26) lib32-flex"

Comment: Have you tried Ubuntu 14.04.2?

Comment: Nope :) I am using Arch right now; I could read ubuntu 14.04 supports kernels 3.13, 3.16 so I do hesitate it makes any difference; Anyways please do add to your answer details of how to compile module cause I am not sure what to do next with the kernel-3.16.7 source unpacked archive? I need just the btusb not to compile the whole core...

Comment: kernel 3.16.0-36 is available to Ubuntu 14.04.2 and already has the necessary patch to the kernel.  Ubuntu uses fixes from newer kernels to keep their LTS kernels functioning for newer hardware

Comment: I used to have kernel 3.16.0 on Arch as well; As I can remember, it was quite unstable causing kernel panic a few times :( I have asus x551ma and kernel 3.16.7 is quite good for it (tested) except the bluetooth support (the broadcom device is too new or similar); I am not about migrate on ubuntu right now so please help me to make my bluetooth work; Today I'll try to download and install linux-headers and tell you my results cause currently I have vmlinux only in the /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r) dir :P

Comment: Also I'll download kernel-3.16.7 sources so please add to your answer the skipped steps of "how-to-compile-btusb-module-from-skretch"; I do want to have the tips by hand :)

Comment: I tried the instructions from your answer which describe "post-compiled-module-integration-into-precompiled-kernel-from-skretch" and I guess it worked; I did miss the linux-headers only to follow the instructions you gave me ;) I had to upgrade the whole os to synch linux and linux-headers versions :P I did the post-compiled btusb.ko.gz module and the hcd integration into my pre-compiled kernel modules; Now I tested the device 04ca 2006 in practice with my mobile phone bluetooth and it worked! Thanks a lot :D

Comment: When I use the command `sudo gzip btusb.ko`, the attempt to load the module with `sudo modprobe btusb` resulted in a dmesg error: `Bluetooth: hci0: urb 0000000037181950 failed to resubmit (2)`.  The module loads fine and works without having it zipped up.

Comment: @AnthonyK do you realize this fix is 7 years old an likely has nothing to do with your issue?

Comment: Hey Jeremy.  Oh dear.  I did not even look at the date!  The steps outlined here however, helped me get Bluetooth on my laptop (a Dell m6700) finally working.  I've had this laptop since 2012 and just gave up on getting BT working.  Then I saw someone at Launchpad say they got it working sometime last year.  I guess I'll soon get the necromancer badge here as well.  I need to start paying attention.  But you did good - these instructions are still valid for kernel version 5.13.0-30-generic.